# mac support of windows code pages

Tags: objective-c, macos, codepages

I'm trying to port some legacy systems from windows to OSX and have come across the need for windows code pages. Is there any support for them in OSX? I haven't been able to find anything  talking about them from quick googling so I assume they are not but I figured I would ask around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSString` supports many Classic Mac, DOS/Windows, and ISO encodings.  See [String Encodings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/String_Encodings) in the NSString documentation.

The complete list of supported string encodings is in [CFStringEncodingExt.h](https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.14/CFStringEncodingExt.h).

Comment: I'm a little unsure how to use that. Would I use that as the encoding for when I am reading in the data from the file?